# Aramaic sections of davening when alone

Tags: tefilla, malach-angel, aramaic

Generally

- When davening alone, the angels hear/take our prayers to Hashem on our behalf  (when Davening with a minyan Hashem hears our prayers directly).  Example [source](http://halachayomit.co.il/en/Default.aspx?HalachaID=2135) (although this discussed Slichot and I am interested in other prayers):

> Since the Heavenly angels do not understand the Aramaic language, one praying alone should not request his needs in this language; rather, one should only ask for his needs in the Holy Tongue (which is what the Hebrew language is based on). Thus, one reciting Selichot alone should not recite those sections which are written in Aramaic. Only when Selichot are being recited in the presence of a Minyan of ten Jewish men should these portions be read, for Hashem’s presence is with them and their prayer shall surely be heard.

- Angels do not understand Aramaic. [example source](http://www.yutorah.org/lectures/lecture.cfm/824933/Rabbi-Moshe-Weinberger/Tiferes-Yisroel-84-Why-Angels-Cannot-Understand-Aramaic)

Do people know of sources discussing the following theme:

- Therefore, should the Aramaic sections of davening be omitted when davening alone?
- Specifically are there any sources discussing Uva letzion, and leaving it out entirely, or leaving out the Aramaic sections when davening without a minyan?  Or is it considered more learning than davening?

Comment: Can you source your "generally" statements?

Comment: Did you try searching the site first? I found http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tefilla+aramaic does that address any of your concerns?

Comment: I have not seen general comments discussing saying all Aramaic sections when davening alone.  Uva Letzion is the main example I was thinking of, but  do not know of others (besides Slichot in the link above).

Comment: Note that many are of the opinion that we can communicate straight with God; we have no need for angels or intermediaries, and we can pray in Aramaic or any other language, since God knows all of them.